# ajax form, modify value with javascript function

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

i have an ajax for submit script on my html page, which loads a php script with form on it....

the form only has one input for a line of comments.... this is sent via post over ajax....

however i need to create a javascript function to link from onclick in a link....

the script will be embedded in the php form page (which already has js on it)

i have around 10 different images, and i need to be able to click on each image, and it will call the function..

```
<a id="image_1" href="javascript: void(0);" onClick="newFunction(this.id)"> image </a>
```

so that the function will be called when you click the image and will transfer the variable ID to the function.....

i need the function to GET the value of the form text box,

then add the

```
 <a id=
```

to the end of the string of data that was in the text box (in this example the id would be

```
 'image_1'
```

then write the new string ( form_data_in_textbox image_1 ) to the text box....

form name + id = myform

text box name + id = comments

this could be quite simple, but im not the best at javascript.... im learning though :)

Comment: Really, one full stop at the end of each sentence is enough. Also, what are you asking here? Do you want a fully written solution, or help on something? If the latter, _what exactly_ do you need help?

Comment: first step of the direction, look at jquery.

Comment: i dont want a full written solution however that would be cool. (1 full stop see - its just a habit). my last attempt was something along the lines of --- imageFunction() { var value = document.getelementbyid[#comments].value ;

Comment: thats just about all i can remember, but i am not sure how to code it.... all i need is to get 'comments' value, add 'id' to end of string, then write string back into text box. maybe 3 lines of js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I got you right, this should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function newFunction(imgId){

        document.getElementById('comments').value = document.getElementById('comments').value + " " + imgId;

    }
</script>

<input id="comments" type="text" value="" size="60"/><br /><br />

<a id="image_1" href="javascript: void(0);" onClick="newFunction(this.id)">image1</a>
<a id="image_2" href="javascript: void(0);" onClick="newFunction(this.id)">image2</a>
<a id="image_3" href="javascript: void(0);" onClick="newFunction(this.id)">image3</a>
<a id="image_4" href="javascript: void(0);" onClick="newFunction(this.id)">image4</a>
<a id="image_5" href="javascript: void(0);" onClick="newFunction(this.id)">image5</a>
```

Comment: lol glad that it helped.
im sure you could do it yourself because it's simple, simple but somehow you got stuck. that's why we are here then :)

Comment: i know how i can manipulate php expressions to do what i want, but the whole javascript logic fools me lol, it may be simple but it doesnt look it :)